# Custom-Post-Type - how can I get the only post by IDnumber?

Tags: custom-post-types

I´m a PHP noop and I want to get the post from a post_type with a specifically ID(for example 64), and than only this.. For Example if there are 3 posts in my post_type (ID 63, ID 64, ID 65) than please show me in frontend the post with ID 64..
Can you help me?
I try this >>>

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'my_pt_name');
$query = new WP_Query( $args);

$my_postid = 64; 
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    echo $content;

endwhile;
```

But in this case, it show me all posts too???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query is completely wrong and mingled. You are using `WP_Query` and `get_post` together and intermingled in one query, which will never work

To retrieve just **one** single post, make use of [`get_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post). You can delete your complete query in your question. Replace it with something like this

```
<?php
   $post_64 = get_post(64); 
   echo $post_64->post_title;
?>
```

Comment: thank you Pieter!!! thats it.. it runs. But the next problem is, I using the plugin qtranslate and it shows me now the title of 2 languages, how can I filter it?

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept my answer. As for your question on the the title and qtranslate, I will not be able to assist there, haven't worked with qtranslate yet, also, it is out of scope of this question. I won't recommend that you post a new question on this here as it will most probably be closed as off topic. You should try try their own forum and maybe stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

You can specify post id in `WP_Query` with `p=`
Here is your code.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'my_pt_name', 'p' => '64' );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        the_content();

    endwhile; 
endif;
```

In above code, I added `p => '64'` to specify post id.

Comment: Where is the `p`. add `'p' => '582'`

Comment: Make sure your custom post type name is `my_pt_name` and post id is `582` and it has content in it.

Comment: `p => '64'` should be `'p' => '64'`

Comment: thx @Robert hue, 2!

Answer (score 0):

Now I got this solution with qtranslate 2, thank you very much @PieterGoosen for given the right way without `WP_Query`!!!

```
<?php

   $poid = get_post(64);
   echo ppqtrans_use($GLOBALS['q_config']['language'], $poid->post_title, true);
   echo ppqtrans_use($GLOBALS['q_config']['language'], $poid->post_content, true);
?>
```

Comment: but what is the way for solution with WP_Query???